# Is there a good way to replace home directory with tilde in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, path

Im trying to work with a path and replace the home directory with a tilde in bash, Im hoping to get it done with as little external programs as necessary. Is there a way to do it with just bash. I got

```
${PWD/#$HOME/\~}
```

But thats not quite right. It needs to convert:

```
/home/alice to ~
/home/alice/ to ~/
/home/alice/herp to ~/herp
/home/alicederp to /home/alicederp
```

As a note of interest, heres how the bash source does it when converting the [\w value in the prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html):

```
/* Return a pretty pathname.  If the first part of the pathname is
   the same as $HOME, then replace that with `~'.  */
char *
polite_directory_format (name)
     char *name;
{
  char *home;
  int l;

  home = get_string_value ("HOME");
  l = home ? strlen (home) : 0;
  if (l > 1 && strncmp (home, name, l) == 0 && (!name[l] || name[l] == '/'))
    {
      strncpy (tdir + 1, name + l, sizeof(tdir) - 2);
      tdir[0] = '~';
      tdir[sizeof(tdir) - 1] = '\0';
      return (tdir);
    }
  else
    return (name);
}
```

Comment: This is not bash, more like C code. But replacing a string with almost no context is error prone. you sure you want to proceed that way?

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear. The C code is an example of how to do it. Its how bash itself does it. bash being a program written in C. Now I want to do the same in the bash language.

Comment: Can you tell us what it outputs as it is right now?

Comment: Ok, when I said almost no context, there is actually quite a risk to do such a thing. the "~" expansion is only valid in a shell environment. So ~ -> home directory expansion is a shell feechure, if you really try to open a file from other than bash, it will fail. for example fopen("~/.bashrc","r") in C gives 0, not what you might expect.

Comment: @pizza I think using pretty pathnames like this is handy for user output (e.g. printing pathnames to the screen), but +1 for mentioning a risk if used for program input.

Comment: zsh users: In zsh, this is just `print -D $PWD`.

Comment: zsh users: in zsh, this is just `${(D)"$(PWD)"}`, using an expression expansion.  (The `(D)` and Kevin's `-D` are alike by design.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [this unix.stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207214):

> If you're using bash, then the `dirs` builtin has the desired
>   behavior:
>
> ```
> dirs +0
> ~/some/random/folder
> ```

That probably uses Bash's own C code that you pasted there. :)

And here's how you could use it:

```
dir=...    # <- Use your own here.

# Switch to the given directory; Run "dirs" and save to variable.
# "cd" in a subshell does not affect the parent shell.
dir_with_tilde=$(cd "$dir" && dirs +0)
```

Note that this will only work with directory names that already exist.

Comment: You could do `dir_with_tilde="$(cd "${dir}" && dirs +0)"` as a one-liner...

But, this doesn't work if the directory doesn't exist, since you can't change to a non-existent directory. You might be constructing a path to create and want to log it in a friendly way.

Comment: Yeah, this is a better way that I suggested below.  Thanks for the tip on the `dirs` command :)

Comment: `dirs +0` doesn't work in zsh, but here's a variant that works on both zsh and bash: `dirs -p | head -1`

Answer (score 21):

I don't know of a way to do it directly as part of a variable substitution, but you can do it as a command:

```
[[ "$name" =~ ^"$HOME"(/|$) ]] && name="~${name#$HOME}"
```

Note that this doesn't do exactly what you asked for: it replaces "/home/alice/" with "~/" rather than "~".  This is intentional, since there are places where the trailing slash is significant (e.g. `cp -R ~ /backups` does something different from `cp -R ~/ /backups`).

Comment: @Steinar: It should do what you want -- the `${name#$HOME}` part takes `$name` and removes `$HOME` from the front (i.e. "/documents" in your example). Is it possible you had a typo in it?

Comment: @Dennis: Steinar's solution has the same bug that `"${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"` has -- in OP's example, it'd turn "/home/alicederp" into "~derp". This can be fixed, but at the cost of losing a fair bit of that readability. Also, if you do use it, please double-quote the variable reference (i.e. `echo "$name"`) to limit unexpected parsing.

Comment: if you don't have support for ``[[ =~ ]]`` \*cough\*msys\*cough\* you can also get it done with ``tildewd=$(pwd | sed -E "s-^$HOME($|(/.*))-~\2-")``.

Comment: Does the assignment replace all occurrences of $HOME with ~, or just the first one? In the former case, it should be fixed.

Comment: @MihaiDanila It only replaces `$HOME` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: This answer works well, you can make it into a simple function one-liner (mainly because you can't use code blocks on StackOverflow comments) as:

`home_relative() { local indir="$(realpath --no-symlinks $1)"; [[ "$indir" =~ ^"$HOME"(/|$) ]] && indir="~${indir#$HOME}"; echo "$indir"; }`

Use with: `name=$(home_relative $name)` (quote if you're worried about spaces)